# Automatically strip invalid characters from Windows filenames

Tags: windows-7, filenames

I often paste titles of PDFs into their filenames so I can easily search for them.  They often have invalid characters like newlines or `:`, and Windows pops up a stupid error and then reverts the filename to its original:

[image]

I don't care about those characters and would be perfectly happy if it replaced them with `-` or removed them entirely.  Is there some way I can do this?  Any system setting for disabling this prompt?

The best I can think of is an AutoHotkey script with its own keyboard shortcut for "paste clipboard but remove invalid characters first", which is what I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using [this AutoHotkey keyboard shortcut](https://gist.github.com/823381), which works ok, but isn't "automatic":

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Win+V: Paste as plain text from clipboard
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#v::
   Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
   ClipBoard = %ClipBoard% ; Convert to plain text
   Send ^v ; For best compatibility: SendPlay
   Sleep 50 ; Don't change clipboard while it is pasted! (Sleep > 0)
   ClipBoard = %Clip0% ; Restore original ClipBoard
   VarSetCapacity(Clip0, 0) ; Free memory
Return

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Win+Alt+V: Paste plain text only, stripping characters unsafe for filenames
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!v:: ; paste without formatting
  StringReplace, clipboardt, clipboard, `r`n, %A_Space%, All
  clipboardt := RegExReplace(clipboardt, "` {2,}", "` ")
  StringLeft, 1st, clipboardt, 1
  IfInString, 1st, %A_Space%
    StringTrimLeft, clipboardt, clipboardt, 1
  StringRIght, last, clipboardt, 1
  IfInString, last, %A_Space%
    StringTrimRight, clipboardt, clipboardt, 1
;Send {Raw}%clipboardt%

  Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
  ClipBoard = %clipboardt% ; Convert to plain text
  Send ^v ; For best compatibility: SendPlay
  Sleep 50 ; Don't change clipboard while it is pasted! (Sleep > 0)
  ClipBoard = %Clip0% ; Restore original ClipBoard
  VarSetCapacity(Clip0, 0) ; Free memory
  clipboardt =
return
```

Answer (score 2):

I do activate this ahk code when needed for that purpose. A ctrl+alt+shift+g (or whatever you chose) will automatically copy and replace the forbidden characters by underscore (or what you want). (You don't really need to fully understand it to customized it).

```
!^+g::                              ;  Alt(!) CTRL(^) shift(+) G ----------------  replace \? <>/\\\*""|: by _ 
clipboard =                        ; empty clipboard
Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}{ESC}     ; send the ctrl C command to copy text in clipboard
ClipWait                           ; wait until there is something in clip bord
Removesign := RegExReplace(clipboard, "[\? <>/\\\*""|:]", "_")  ; run the regex on the clipboard content and save it in Removesign 
clipboard = %Removesign%           ; send Removesign to clipboard
ClipWait
return
```

Answer (score 1):

12 years later this issue still persists on Windows 10 and Windows 11. Why would we want to paste text with formatting in filenames anyway since it's impossible? I am confused why they don't make it by default to strip any formatting from clipboard when pasting in the filename field in File Explorer...

But now there is a tweak for this in [Windows PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/) called **[Paste as Plain Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/paste-as-plain-text)** where you can assign a shortcut to paste text without formatting.

[image]

> PowerToys Paste as Plain Text enables you to paste text stored in your
> clipboard, excluding any text-formatting, using a quick key shortcut.
> Any formatting included with the clipboard text will be replaced with
> an unformatted version of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my music files. I ended up writing a Java program to rename everything. I was lucky since there were some free mp3 ID3 metadata libraries available. I'm not sure if there is a free library available to read PDF metadata. There is a discussion about it [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/291084).

After a lot of searching, I found this tool ([A-PDF Rename](http://www.a-pdf.com/rename/)) which claims to be able to rename PDF files based on metadata. I have never seen or heard of it before. Purchase and download at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com) script that would replace the invalid characters in your clipboard.

I don't use AutoIT myself, so I don't know the scripting language, but many people seem to be manipulating the clipboard contents using `ClipGet()` & `ClipPut(value)`.  I didn't see a good way to "monitor" the clipboard, mainly I saw loops that slept for 1 second between running.

I think this is what @Hello71 mean.  Hope this point you in the right direction.